# display eror on voting button like stack overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not getting any error and also this is not working the way I want it to be.
I have a jQuery upvote plugin in my project. To avoid span I am validating user input on every vote. Everything is working and I am getting the error If I try to span the voting functionality from my php file. The problem is when I try to show that message on the screen just like stack overflow.

Currently I have this but the out is not what I wanted:

```
 <script>
var callback = function(data) {

$.ajax({
    url: 'voting.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { id: data.id, up: data.upvoted, down: data.downvoted, star: data.starred },
    success: function(result) {  
    $("[data-id='" + data.id + "']").html(result);
} 
});
};
 $('.upvote').upvote({callback: callback});

</script>
```

Output where the error replaces the up and down vote :

[image]

**My html which has a span tag but not sure how to use it?**

```
  if($RES['counter'] === '1'){
 echo '
         <td>
           <div  data-id='.$id.' class="upvote upvote-serverfault">
            <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="upvote upvote-on" title="This idea is helpful"></a>
            <span class="count">'.$counter.'</span>
            <a class="downvote"></a>
            <span class="votingFeedback"></span>
          </div>
      </td>';  
    }
    else 
        if($RES['counter'] === '-1'){
    echo '
      <td>
        <div  data-id='.$id.' class="upvote upvote-serverfault">
            <a style="cursor:pointer;" class="upvote upvote-down" title="This idea is helpful"></a>
            <span class="count">'.$counter.'</span>
            <a class="downvote downvote-on"></a>
            <span class="votingFeedback"></span>  
        </div>
      </td>';
    }
```

Comment: What's the error

Comment: no error, just the problem with the output

Comment: @Sinto I was trying to make it like stack overflow. When you try spanning up vote button on stack overflow you get the error. just like that

Comment: So you need to show the info as a popup for few seconds?

Comment: @Sinto right that's what I was looking for

Comment: So you want to display the error in span votingFeedback ?

Comment: @SmitRaval that was my initial plan. But if you have something else in mind I am completely open with it

Comment: Check  my answer. You can show the message in span and then using css you can change the look and feel of the message. Hope it will help. @samscoot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'voting.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { id: data.id, up: data.upvoted, down: data.downvoted, star: data.starred },
    success: function(result) {  
    $("[data-id='" + data.id + "']").find("span.votingFeedback").text(result);
} 
});
```

Using this you can show the error in the respective `span` element with class `votingFeedback`.

Comment: Also please mark the answer as approved if it has solved your issue so it can help someone in future. :) @samscoot

Comment: yes it's working and I'll accept the answer shortly.Thank you